# How to set the value of chrome.privacy.network.webRTCIPHandlingPolicy using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Would anyone know how to set the value of `chrome.privacy.network.webRTCIPHandlingPolicy` to `disable_non_proxied_udp` using the Selenium ChromeDriver?

I am unsure if this is done through `set_experimental_options` or `set_desired_capabilities`.

Answer (score 2):

As per the discussion [disable_non_proxied_udp allows non-proxied TURN](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=767304) enabling *"Prevent WebRTC from leaking local IP addresses"* will set `chrome.privacy.network.webRTCIPHandlingPolicy` to **`disable_non_proxied_udp`**.

The argument `--force-webrtc-ip-handling-policy` overrides the *WebRTC IP handling policy* to mimic the behavior when WebRTC IP handling policy is specified in Preferences.

So as a *Preference* you need to set `enforce-webrtc-ip-permission-check` as **`True`**.

So the effective code block:

- *Python*:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_experimental_option("prefs", { \
    "enforce-webrtc-ip-permission-check": True 
    })
  options.add_argument("force-webrtc-ip-handling-policy")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
  ```
- *Java*:

  ```
  HashMap<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<>();
  prefs.put("enforce-webrtc-ip-permission-check", true);
  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
  options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
  options.addArguments("force-webrtc-ip-handling-policy"); 
  WebDriver driver =  new ChromeDriver(options); 
  driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
  ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am looking for a way to prevent webrtc from leaking my public ip by using the ip of my proxy server.  Is there any way to accomplish this by changing the webrtc ip handling policy?  Thanks again.

Comment: It seems that when I configure selenium to use http or socks proxies, that my public ip still leaks.  I assume that this is due to the fact that udp is not supported by most proxies (as mentioned in the page you linked), so the ip handling policy falls back on mode 3, uses tcp and/or a falling back on a connection to a TURN server leaves my original public ip still visible?

Comment: @AsiaN That's pretty much possible.

Comment: As in preventing WebRTC from leaking my public IP (without disabling it) is possible or not possible?  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
    preferences = {"webrtc.ip_handling_policy": "disable_non_proxied_udp", "webrtc.multiple_routes_enabled": False,
                   "webrtc.nonproxied_udp_enabled": False, "profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}

    option.add_experimental_option("prefs", preferences)
```